# Golang (cgo) - Arbitrary void* interface

Tags: go, cgo

I am wrapping a C library that has a struct with a void* data field that can be used to arbitrarily hold data.  What would be the best way (if it's even possible) to wrap this in idiomatic Go?

The struct is quite simply:

```
typedef struct _Foo {
    void * data;
} Foo;
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
type Foo C.Foo

func (f *Foo) SetData(data interface{}) {
    f.data = unsafe.Pointer(&data)
}

func (f *Foo) Data() interface{} {
    return (interface{})(unsafe.Pointer(f.data))
}
```

This doesn't work, and is clearly the wrong approach anyways.

I have successfully set a void* data with a length field using a []byte source, but this length-less interface eludes me.

Comment: For the curious the end goal was this - https://github.com/boj/goenet - although still a bit buggy, so beware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming back to this after several more months of Go under my belt I came up with the following (updated, thanks zupa) solution.

```
func (f *Foo) SetData(data interface{}) {
    f.data = unsafe.Pointer(&data)
}

func (f *Foo) Data() interface{} {
    return unsafe.Pointer(f.data)
}
```

And can be used in the following manner:

```
type Player struct {
    Name string
}

p := &Player{
    Name: "Player1",
}

f.SetData(p)

log.Print(f.Data().(*Player).Name) // Outputs: Player1
```

Comment: why do you have to store data in `&FooData{}`?

Comment: I was wrapping the ENet library awhile back.  You aren't required to store anything in the data field, but it is there as a mechanism for the client library to connect a Peer to an in-game construct like a Player - http://enet.bespin.org/structENetPeer.html#a1873959810db7ac7a02da90469ee384e

Comment: sorry, my question wasn't clear. I'm not asking why you have to store data; I'm asking why you wrap `data` in `&FooData{}` instead of using `f.data = unsafe.Pointer(&data)` directly.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I honestly cannot remember why it ended up such a convoluted mess.  Edited the answer with the correct code.

Comment: Okay, cheers! For anyone reading this, I asked myself reading the snippet whether the GC will free whatever is pointed to by an unsafe.Pointer. No, it won't. [Explained here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/yNis7bQG_rY/yaJFoSx1hgIJ)

Comment: has something related changed in golang since this? I just tested the code and I'm getting a panic when trying to type assert f.Data() into a Player : "panic: interface conversion: interface {} is unsafe.Pointer, not *main.Player". Can't seem to type assert back to a Player pointer or even cast the result in to a Player pointer with (*Player) : "cannot convert f.Data() (type interface {}) to type *Player: need type assertion"

Answer (score 3):

if you take an adres of an `interface`, you're taking address of a value type (roughly `struct { tInfo *typeInfo, payload uintPtr}`), not the data "boxed" by the interface. The payload field can hold the real data if they fit into a machne word, otherwise that field holds a pointer to the actual payload. But these are implementation details and should not be worked directly with, IMO.

I would go non generic, like (untested code, schema only):

```
func (f *Foo) SetT(p *T) {
        (*C.Foo)(f).data = unsafe.Pointer(p)
}
```

and

```
func (f *Foo) GetT() *T {
        return (*T)((*C.Foo)(f).data)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I have been considering since I posted my question.

Comment: You could also use `reflect.Elem()` and `reflect.Pointer()` to get a `uintptr` to the interface's contained value.

Comment: [reflect.func (Value) Pointer](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Pointer): _"It panics if v's Kind is not Chan, Func, Map, Ptr, Slice, or UnsafePointer."_