# Why casting interface{} to cgo types is not allowed?

Tags: go, cgo

It's more of a technical question, not really an issue. Since we don't have variadic functions in cgo and there's currently no valid solution, I wonder if it'd be possible to cast interface{} to cgo types. So this would allow us to have more dynamic functions. I'm pretty sure we're not even allowed to assign types in a dynamic way to arguments in exported (//export) functions, neither the use of ellipsis is allowed. So what's the reason behind all those limits?

Thanks for answering.

```
import "C"

//export Foo
func Foo(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    
}
```

Comment: There is no “casting” in Go, so what is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I mean type conversion. I want to convert interface{} into a cgo type (*C.char for example).

Comment: You can’t convert an interface to anything, because it’s a container for a dynamically typed value. It would really help to have an example of what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I updated my original post with an example. Let's say that the function that it's being exported is actually called from C and we're unaware of the type that we might receive (type of each argument is unknown). How should we proceed? Arguments might be anything: from a string, to an integer and so on.

Comment: You are exporting a function to C, so you would use the same techniques as you would from C. You often encapsulate multiple types via void pointers, you could have multiple arguments, or a struct containing various options. You can’t export things that are not valid in C.

Comment: Thing is I'm never sure about the value that is being received in Go. Might be a string, might be an int, it could be a lot of stuff. It's actually determined by the user, it's user data. So that's what my problem is. So Go doesn't actually allow me to manipulate the data however I want.

Comment: Does this:  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339603/golang-cgo-arbitrary-void-interface> answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C compilers are allowed, but not required, to return different types using different return mechanisms.  For instance, some C compilers might return `float` results in the `%f0` register, `double` results in the `%f0:f1` register *pair*, integer results in the `%d0` register, and pointer results in the `%a0` register.

What this means for the person writing the Cgo interface for Go is that they must, in general, *handle each kind of these C functions differently*.  In other words, it's not possible to write:

```
generic_type Cfunc(ctype1 arg1, ctype2 arg2) { ... }
```

We must *know*, at compile time, that `Cfunc` returns float/double/<some-integer-type>/<some-pointer-type> so that we can grab the *correct register(s)* and stuff its (or their) value(s) into the Cgo return-value slot, where the Cgo interface can get it and wrap it up for use in Go.

What this means for you, as a user of a Go compiler that implements Cgo wrappers to call C functions, is that *you have to know the right type*.  There is no generalized answer; there is no way to use `interface{}` here.  You must communicate the *exact, correct type* to the Cgo layer, so that the Cgo layer can use that exact, correct type information to generate the correct machine code at compile time.

If the C compiler writers had some way of flagging their code so that, e.g., at link time, the *linker* could pull in the right "save correct register to memory" location, that would enable the Cgo wrapper author to use the linker to automagically find the C function's type at link time.  But these C compilers don't offer this ability to the linkers.

Is your particular compiler one of these?  We don't know: you didn't say.  But:

> I'm pretty sure we're not even allowed to assign types in a dynamic way to arguments in exported (//export) functions, neither the use of ellipsis is allowed. So what's the reason behind all those limits?

That's correct, and the (slightly theoretical) example above is *a* reason.  (I constructed this example by mixing actual techniques from 68k C compilers and SPARC C compilers, so I don't think there's any single C compiler like this.  But examples like this did exist in the past, and SPARC systems still return integers in %o0, or %o0+%o1 on V8 SPARC, vs floating point in %f0 or %f0+%f1.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I was looking for.